# Method.Invoke without knowing the paramaters

Tags: java

I am using Method.Invoke in java to dynamically call methods in another class. The only issue is that if the methods have paramaters i need to start that in the class.getDeclaredMethod("method", something.class) or else it wont see those methods. The issue with this that i don't know when calling the methods what the parameters will be. How do I get around this?

Also I have done this in C# and its easy and does not require me to state the parameters but this is in Java.

Here is the code that does the Invoke:

```
public void DoCommand(String msg){
        System.out.println(msg);
        String[] temp = msg.split(" ");
        String command = temp[0];

        Class c = commander.getClass();

        try {
            Object obj = c.newInstance();
            try {
                System.out.println("'" + command + "'");
                Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod(command);

                Object[] pars = new Object[temp.length];
                for(int i = 0; i < pars.length; i++){
                    pars[i] = temp[i + 1];
                }

                if((String)pars[pars.length - 1] == null){
                    pars[pars.length - 1] = socket;
                }

                Parameter[] paramaters = method.getParameters();
                Object[] endParameters = AltimitConverter.ConvertParameters(pars, paramaters);

                try {
                    method.invoke(obj, endParameters);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {}
            }catch (NoSuchMethodException e){
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
```

So how do I call different methods with different parameters without stating the parameters when getting the method.

This is the C# version that does work:

```
private static void DoCommand(string msg, Socket soc){
        string[] temp = msg.Split (' ');
        string command = temp [0];

        Type type = commandObject.GetType ();
        MethodBase commandFunction = type.GetMethod (command);

        if (commandFunction != null) {
            object[] pars = new object[temp.Length - 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < pars.Length; i++) {
                pars [i] = temp [i + 1];
            }

            if ((string)pars [pars.Length - 1] == "") {
                pars [pars.Length - 1] = soc;
            }


            ParameterInfo[] paramaters = commandFunction.GetParameters ();
            object[] endParamaters = AltimitConverter.ConvertParams (pars, paramaters);

            if (commandFunction != null) {
                try {
                    commandFunction.Invoke (commandObject, endParamaters);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Debug.Log (e);
                }
            } else {
                Debug.Log ("commandFunction is null");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried method overloading?

Comment: how would that look? they wont all be named the same and if i added more classes then used it would do the same issue.

Comment: Given that multiple methods may share the same name as a result of overloading, how do you propose to identify the correct method without relying in some way on the parameters?

Comment: @Zarch You could have two methods, one with default empty constructor and the one method with your parameters. You would always call the empty constructor and it  could act as builder for the other overloaded method, getting the parameters and passing them to the parameterized constructor and invoking that method. When dealing with reflection there is never pretty solution.

Comment: I know what overloading is that wasnt my point. so i have a method GetName(), GetName(Integer num), SetTime(Date time) and I got a method by name of GetName it wouldn't matter what the parameters were until i invoked it with the correct parameters. all that matters is that there is some kind of method named GetName or SetTime and worried about it have the right parameters when called.

Comment: if i use getDeclaredMethod it wont find the method unless i tell it the type.class's it has when using getDeclaredMethod

Comment: You have a critical misunderstanding.  Methods `getName()` and `getName(Integer)` are *different methods*.  Having obtained a `Method` object reflecting one of them, you cannot invoke it with a (possibly-empty) argument list appropriate for the other.

Comment: yeah i get that too. say i looked for GetName method with not know its paramaters and it sees them. and then i invoke with and Integer parameter it will invoke the GetName(Integer num) method.

Comment: NO.  If you get a `Method` object reflecting a no-arg method `getName()`, and you try to invoke it with a non-empty parameter list, then the invocation will FAIL with an `IllegalArgumentException`.  `Method` objects reflect *specific* methods with *specific* signatures.  Actual arguments are still converted on invocation, if possible, to the type of their corresponding parameters, but if the number of arguments does not match the number of parameters, or if they cannot be correctly converted, then *you lose*.

Comment: *"Why doesn't Java work exactly the same as C#?"* -> Because they are different. If they were the same, only one of them would exist.

Comment: I'm wondering how your C# program works when the class has more than one overload for the method name. According to its documentation, you'll get an `AmbiguousNameException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution. I created a function to take the intended parameters which are strings and convert them to a data type depending on if it looks like a float, Integer, or string. then i send that into another method that gets all methods in a class and get the ones with the method name i am trying to call and then gets the one with the data types i had in the object[] returned from the first method. and then i use the method i got and the converted data types to call the method.

Answer (score 1):

Instances of `java.lang.reflect.Method` reflect specific methods.  Each one is associated with a specific class, has a specific parameter list, and has a specific return type.  When method overloading is in play, each of the overloaded methods will be reflected by a distinct `Method` object; these are not interchangeable.

If you need to account for selecting among overloaded methods, then you can do so only with reference to the number and types of the intended arguments.  If you have to rely on the arguments themselves to determine matching parameter types, then you're looking at duplicating Java's method-resolution logic, which is complex.

In the event that you need only worry about looking up a non-overloaded method declared by the subject class itself (i.e. not inherited) then you can invoke `getDeclaredMethods()` on the `Class` object and scan the resulting array of `Method` objects for one with the correct name.

You can go a little way into overloaded methods while preserving your sanity if different overloads are distinguished by different numbers of parameters, or maybe if there are specific limits on the parameter type patterns you need to account for, but at that point you really should be asking yourself whether there's a better way.  This kind of design absolutely begs for trouble.

Comment: In point of fact, the OP's C# code doesn't work either, and has exactly the same problem.  C# simply trades a compile-time error for a run-time exception.  C#'s `GetMethod(string)` is simply a convenience call for getting a method that's known not to be overloaded.  Calling it with the name of an overloaded method throws an `AmbiguousMatchException`

Comment: I have a whole server using that command and have never once ran into that issue

https://github.com/zarcha/MMO_Server_CSharp